# matlab: I want to convert a cellarray to an array?

Tags: matlab

Conversion?

```
array(1:3) = cellArray{1:3}; 
% this fails:  "Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch."
```

### note:  I know how to do this in a loop.  Looking for matlab direct route.

%% Contents of cellArray %%

```
K>> cellArray{1:3}

ans =

11


ans =

f0


ans =

05
```

Comment: How do you expect `f0` to be converted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [cell2mat.](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html)

> `A = cell2mat(C)` converts cell array `C` with contents of the same data type into a single array, `A`.

Answer (score 1):

If all cells are of the same type, and share similar first dimension, then

```
array = [cellArray{:}];
```

should work